# .htaccess redirect rule for for removing article id

Tags: .htaccess, joomla

I want to redirect the following URLs:

**From:** http://www.example.com/13-articlename 
 
**TO:** http://www.example.com/articlename

And I have following code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} id=13
RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.example.com/articlename [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

In your rewrite you are expecting a querystring parameter of `id` however in your example it is actually part of the URL.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule (\d+)-([^/]*) $2 [R=301,L]
```

- `(\d+)` = match any digits
- `-` = a hyphen
- `([^/]*)` = any characters except a forward slash
- `$2` = redirect to the second matching group - `([^/]*)`
- `[R=301]` = use a HTTP 301 redirect (omit if you want to have it rewrite instead of redirect)
- `[L]` = Last rule (don't process following rules)

You can test at http://htaccess.madewithlove.be/

```
input url
http://www.example.com/13-articlename

output url
http://www.example.com/articlename

debugging info
1 RewriteEngine on  
2 RewriteBase / 
3 RewriteRule (\d+)-([^/]*) $2 [R=301,L]
This rule was met, the new url is http://www.example.com/articlename 
Test are stopped, because of the R in your RewriteRule options. 
A redirect will be made with status code 301
```

Comment: +1 for the test link. But Joomla isn't happy with just this change in .htaccess. It gives 404 errors.