# Joomla redirects any URL that starts with a correct itemId

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, joomla

My Joomla website got hacked because of the exploit in december. This made google mark it as a dangerous site. Not good.

I cleaned it up and reported to google that I had done so.

The hackers/spanners put some files like "1_junk_shopping_blah.html" and indexed them on google after editing my htaccess file to make it redirect to them directly.

After fixing everything I notice that www.example.com/1_junk_shopping_blah.html redirects to the article with itemId 1. Joomla apparently strips everything after the leading number and uses it as a valid url. Google thinks I still have the spam online and my site remains marked as malicious.

I tried to put similar urls on another not hacked Joomla site, and it redirects the same way, so it does not seem to be a problem that resulted from the hacking but more a problem with the way Joomla is set up.

Why does Joomla redirect urls that are not correct? How can I fix this? I can edit the core of Joomla if necessary, but I would need some pointers as to not mess it up instead of fixing it. Or can I maybe just put something in my .htaccess?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I "solved" this with some PHP code in our template, I put solved in quotes because it's not perfect. It will block valid urls that have a leading digit.. One of our clients actually has an article title beginning with the number 5 so in their case this wouldn't work.. But on another site that got tagged malicious, it worked perfectly because all of their titles are alphabetic in the beginning.

In your template below the Restricted Access line ( all good templates should have this ) .. the following code will detect if the url begins with a front slash and is followed by a number, if it is then it sets the 404 header and redirects to an actual page I know doesn't exist in order to show the 404 page..

As you might imagine, if you have a custom 404 that begins with "4" this could cause an infinite loop, so it's again.. not perfect. I just wrote this to solve their immediate problem.

```
if (preg_match("#^/[0-9]#", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    header("HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found");
    header("Location: /page-not-found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Check malware on your site by doing following steps

1. [Sitecheck by sucuri.net](http://sitecheck.sucuri.net/scanner/)
2. than try to find all unauthorized modifications in Joomla files.
   After (or better before!) clearing the site from suspect code,
   change all passwords, whether for `FTP, MySQL, SMTP` authentication
   `(Site -> Configuration -> Server -> Mail)` and to the administration
   panel!

## For removing IDs from URLs

1. https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/988/remove-article-id-from-joomla-3-url
2. [Get rid of ID (category and article) from URL (Joomla 3.3 / 3.4 / 3.5)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26168517/get-rid-of-id-category-and-article-from-url-joomla-3-3-3-4)

I recommend to use 3rd party extensions because its much easier way to prevent ugly URLs.

Comment: Thank you for the pointers to the malware check etc, but my problem is not that the IDs are in the URLs when using the site, rather the fact that arbitrary addresses redirect to articles instead of giving a 404. I have solved the problem partly by removing the articles with IDs that google had listed as "URL injection" and recreating them with new IDs.

The problem is also posted about here http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=712&t=810399